# why "set aside" is used?

Tags: grammar

> Smaller quantities (of herbicides) are used in forestry, pasture systems, and management of areas set aside as wildlife habitat.

What is the meaning of

> set aside as wildlife habitat."

Before omitting which, what was the original sentence?
I think it is correct to say:

> Smaller quantities (of herbicides) are used in forestry, pasture systems, and management of areas **which are set aside** as wildlife habitat.

It is edited version.

Comment: You shouldn't change your question after an answer has been given to the original question. I'll add a P.P.S to address your new question.

Comment: @TRomano, Thank you for your comment. I got down vote for my answer because OP changed the question.Your comment helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original is flawed. You would need to say

"... management of areas set aside *as* wildlife habitat".

where "as" = for the purpose of, having the function of

P.S. The clause "set aside as wildlife habit" modifies "areas". It could also be written "...areas *which have been* set aside as wildlife habitat".

P.P.S.  "set aside as X" = dedicated to the purpose of X.

Answer (score 1):

> Smaller quantities (of herbicides) are used in forestry, pasture
>   systems, and management of areas in which they are set aside as
>   wildlife habitat.

In this sentence **"they"** refer to the herbicides.

Comment: Please leave a comment for your down vote. OP changed the question after posting answer.
When ever you downvote leave a comment.

Comment: Excuse me Ramya. I changed it before seeing your comments. I will never repeat it. thanks for helping me.